# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" When setting a UILabel's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

I'm a student of iOS programming working through the Big Nerd Ranch book. I see that lots of other people have caught the same exception "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but can't find out what's causing it in my code.

It's happening in this method where I try to set the text of a UITableViewCell's UILabel.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BNRItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    //Set BNRItem instances to equal a given object in the items[] array
    BNRItem *item = items[indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.itemName;  //This is the line where the exception happens
    cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber;
    cell.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", item.valueInDollars];
    cell.thumbnailView.image = item.thumbNail;

    return cell;

}
```

In the BNRItem implementation I'm using archiving to store the values of its properties (which are used to set the text in the text labels, which is where the exception gets thrown).

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.itemName forKey:@"itemName"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.serialNumber forKey:@"serialNumber"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.dateCreated forKey:@"dateCreated"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.itemKey forKey:@"itemKey"];
    [aCoder encodeInt:self.valueInDollars forKey:@"valueInDollars"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.thumbNail forKey:@"thumbnail"];
}



- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _itemName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"itemName"];
        _serialNumber= [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"serialNumber"];
        _dateCreated = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dateCreated"];
        _itemKey = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"itemKey"];
        _valueInDollars = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"valueInDollars"];
        _thumbNail = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"thumbnail"];


    }
    return self;
}



- (id) initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
         valueInDollars: (int) value
           serialNumber: (NSString *) sNumber;
    {

    self = [super init];


    //Give the instance variables initial values
    [self setItemName:name]; //point to self since its the initializer of the object
    [self setSerialNumber:sNumber];
    [self setValueInDollars:value];
    _dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc]init];

    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] init];
    NSString *key = [uuid UUIDString];
    _itemKey = key;

    return self; //return self so that you can assign it to a variable
}
```

EDIT - Here is the rest of the implementation for the BNRItem. Namely, a method to randomize the properties of the BNRItem and another to give it a thumbnail image

```
//Creates a BNRItem instance with a random name, random value and random serial number
+ (id)randomItem {
//Create an array of three adjectives
NSArray *randomAdjectiveList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Kyle", @"Jerry", nil];

//Create an array of three nouns
NSArray *randomNounList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cheese", @"Meat", @"Vegetables",    
nil];

NSInteger adjectiveIndex = rand() % [randomAdjectiveList count];
NSInteger nounIndex = rand() % [randomNounList count];

NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [randomAdjectiveList   
objectAtIndex:adjectiveIndex], [randomNounList objectAtIndex:nounIndex]];

int randomValue = rand () % 100;

NSString *randomSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%c",
                                '0' + rand() % 10,
                                'A' + rand() % 26,
                                '0' + rand() % 10,
                                'A' + rand() % 26,
                                '0' + rand() % 10 ];

BNRItem *newItem = [[self alloc] initWithItemName:randomName
                                   valueInDollars:randomValue
                                     serialNumber:randomSerialNumber];

return newItem;

}




- (void) setThumbNailFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
CGSize origImageSize = image.size;

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

//Figure out a scaling ratio to make sure we maintain the same aspect ratio
float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width / origImageSize.width, newRect.size.height /  
origImageSize.height);

//Createa a transparent bitmap context with a scaling factor equal to that of the screen

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);

//Create a path that is a rounded rectangle
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect cornerRadius:5.0];

//Make all subsequent drawing clip to this rounded rectangle
[path addClip];

//Center the image in the thumbnail rectangle
CGRect projectRect;
projectRect.size.width = ratio * origImageSize.width;
projectRect.size.height  = ratio * origImageSize.height;
projectRect.origin.x = (newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width) / 2.0;
projectRect.origin.y = (newRect.size.height - projectRect.size.height);


//Draw the image on it
[image drawInRect:projectRect];

//Get the image from the image context; keep it as our thumbnail
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.thumbNail = smallImage;

//Clea image context resources; we're done
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


}
```

The `UITableViewCell` was created with a xib and has 4 outlets (3 labels and one image).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRItemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *serialNumberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *valueLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnailView;

@end
```

I haven't learned Core Data yet but it's coming up, the problem is that I need to get what I have working so that I can keep modifying it with the textbook instructions. Any help's appreciated!

Comment: Does BNRItemCell have have a serialNumberLabel, property of type UILabel?

Comment: Yup. I'm editing the OP and adding the .h for BNRItemCell

Comment: -1 for not quoting the exact and complete error message.

Comment: As @HotLicks pointed out: please show us the complete error message. Could the problem be in your `BNRItem`?

Comment: do you know at which line are you getting this error??

Comment: Full error message is: "2014-04-02 14:01:10.156 Homepwner[26215:90b] -[__NSCFString itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1092658f0". The line is indicated in the OP, "cell.nameLabel.text = item.itemName;". When I comment out all of the attempts to point the UITableViewCell labels at the BNRItem properties the error disappears and the UITableViewCells simply display with the default text as set in the xib. I have a feeling the problem is in BNRItem too, the archiving code in the OP is all from that, I'm wondering if the problem is in the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `;` after `serialNumber: (NSString *) sNumber;` which causes the error. Remove it & try again.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eye, I got rid of it but still getting the error though.

Comment: Did you link up the `IBOutlet` of `UITableView` in Storyboard?

Comment: Nope, not in Storyboard. I just control-dragged from the xib.

Comment: and I assume you have imported `UIKit`, right? I saw you included `Foundation`, but not `UIKit` (well, but you can run the App, so you probably did). Try to comment out the codes line by line to locate the error

Comment: Yup, when I comment out the lines that point the UITableViewCell's labels to BNRItem properties the error disappears. It's definitely got something to do with the BNRItem class, I posted the rest of the class' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will help you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

 BNRItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRItemCell"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil)
{
 cell = [[BNRItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
//Set BNRItem instances to equal a given object in the items[] array
BNRItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];// try this as well
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.itemName];  // must try this
cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber;
cell.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", item.valueInDollars];
cell.thumbnailView.image = item.thumbNail;

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Ah still getting the error :(. The specific message is "2014-04-02 15:30:43.352 Homepwner[34104:90b] -[__NSCFString itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10951fe00"

Comment: Ah it's still not working. The code is copied directly from the BNR textbook too, I'm assuming that the code itself isn't dysfunctional. Could there be something to do with the way the files are stored that's causing this?

Comment: the problem is that your itemname has not any value and you are setting its text to label and thats why it its giving you that message

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that problem as well. I went into the BNRItemCell.xib file and opened up the document outliner, right clicked on some of the labels in the view trees to check out the reference outlets. I notices that they were hooked up to the file's Owner in the xib as well as the IBOutlet's in the BNRItemCell.h file. I unhooked them from the File's Owner and it fixed the problem. Not sure if that is your issue, but check it out.

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up on it, I had a final assignment app for the course so I jumped into that and left the BNR tutorials behind. Thanks for the reply though, it's definitely worth nothing should I run into the issue in the future.